# getting spdx warning even after providing spdx license

Tags: python, solidity, web3py, spdx

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hvr62.png)

python is unable to find "spdx" license I have written on the top, attachment is there, plz help me to find out what is wrong with this code

Comment: You haven't provided an SPDX license number.  However, there is nothing "wrong" with this code.  That's just a caution.  Does it work?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

UNLICENSED is used when you do not want to specify a license.
Try using this instead:

```
SPDX-License-Identifier:MIT;
```